# Where and how can I make my own Dwarven Armour?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm the right level now to start making my own Dwarven Armour in Skyrim. And I'm really excited!

But I don't know what it takes to make it, or where to even begin making it.
Normal forges don't seem to offer an option for it, so if not there. Where?

Answer (score 17):

Normal forges *can* be used to make Dwarven armor (and weapons), but first you need the [Dwarven Smithing Perk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Smithing#Dwarven_Smithing).  This is also true of most [other types of armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing#Skill_Perks).  Dwarven Smithing can be acquired at Smithing level 30.

Crafting Dwarven Equipment required [Dwarven Metal Ingots](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Metal_Ingot#Dwarven_Metal_Ingot) which can be smelted from various pieces of Dwemer scrap metal.  The breakdown for these pieces and how many ingots they produce is:

- Bent Dwemer Scrap Metal - 3 ingots
- Large Decorative Dwemer Strut - 2 ingots
- Large Dwemer Plate Metal - 3 ingots
- Large Dwemer Strut - 3 ingots
- Small Dwemer Plate Metal - 3 ingots
- Solid Dwemer Metal - 5 ingots

These items (along with ingots themselves) can be found lying around in the numerous Dwemer ruins and/or by looting Dwemer Constructs such as spiders and centurions.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarven_Armor_%28Skyrim%29).
"Dwarven Armor can be crafted with the Dwarven Smithing Perk available at Smithing level 30. Dwarven Metal Ingots are used to both craft and improve Dwarven Armor and Weapons. Crafting Dwarven Armor is a very effective way to grind this skill, due to the abundance of Dwarven Metal that can be found throughout the numerous Dwarven ruins in Skyrim. "